# OPTIONS http method: how to implement it properly

Tags: rest, http

I have an application with different resources:

1. **GET** `/report/555`
2. **POST** `/messages`

Now I want to support **OPTIONS** http method in the application. Should I implement one handler for all OPTIONS requests and return `GET, POST` in `Allow` header or it's better to return different responses for each route: only `Allow: GET` for `/report/555` and only `Allow: POST` for `/messages`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning different responses is the correct choice here.

Here is the reasoning.

If you return `Allow: GET, POST` for both `/report/555` and `/messages`,
you are stating that POST is allowed for `/report/555` which is incorrect
and that GET is allowed for `/messages` which is also incorrect.

Therefore, you should return the correct response for each request target.

Using your example specifically, this means you should return `Allow: GET` for `/report/555` and `Allow: POST` for `/messages`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but:

`OPTIONS` should be called on a specific target. It should generally return the verbs available for that target. If you want to find out the options for all endpoints, you need to send your request with a [`request-target`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3) of `*`.

For more information on `OPTIONS`, check out [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7).